# Creating an activity alias returns either 404 or 400

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have just created an activity with the name of `InventorParams`. I would like to add an alias as right now it shows up as: `Guasamt.InventorParams+$LATEST` in the [activities list](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/activities-GET/).

Now when POSTing the following request:

```php
[
"id" => "prod"
]
```

*Laravel will turn this into json. The Authorization header is also present*

to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/activities/:id/aliases. It either returns 400 or 404 errors. The 400 error is presented when using a fully qualified activity name. The 404 error is returned on all of the the following activity names:

- Guasamt.InventorParams+LATEST (without $);
- Guasamt.InventorParams;
- InventorParams;

Now I'm wondering what should be the unqualified name of an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an Activity in FDA it gets a version number (since you just created it, it would be 1). This number needs to be used when creating Activity Alias, which is later used in the Work Item.

Your fully qualified name consist of <your_nick_name>.<activity_name>+<activity_version>. Where <your_nick_name> can be your ClientId if [nickname](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/task2-create-nickname/) was not specified.

Anyway I would recommend to follow the FDA [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/). Another option on how to get quickly up to speed with FDA is to use the [Autodesk Forge Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools) addin to VS Code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what fixed it but I'm guessing adding the version number did the trick.